# Separator in object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following function

```
variable_name = window.variable.map(function (item) {
                          return item.name;
                    });
```

The result of this function is an object like this:

```
[". name1", ". name2", ". name3"]
```

How can I check if my object contains this charecter . and if yes take back an split object without it. Example:

```
["name1", "name2", "name3"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace each `. and whitespace` in item.name with `""` if found.
Regex explaination:

**/[.\s]/g**
**[.\s]** match a single character present in the list below
**.** the literal character .
**\s** match any white space character **[\r\n\t\f ]**
**g** modifier: global. All matches (don't return on first match)

```
variable_name = variable.map(function (item) {
                  return item.name.replace(/[.\s]/g, "");
                });
```

Comment: Yes there are many other ways. But i think regex can give you more flexibility to search in desired character pattern